# Container running on ACI on a VNET is unable to reach internet addresses (Outbound connections)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

We have a container running via ACI on a VNET that recently has stopped being able to reach internet addresses (google.com, Azure SQL Databases, etc). I have brought up several other containers in the VNET as well as in brand new VNETS that are created by the "az container create" command and they all display the same behavior. I have tested with stock ubuntu, and alpine images (in addition to our original custom image), and have even tried Microsoft's Hello World image. In every instance (every vnet and region I have tried them in) ping to any external address fails (but internal addresses don't), but DNS does resolve. We get the following network interfaces (with the eth0 getting a VNET/Subnet local address)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:57:E0:61:78:DF
          inet addr:10.202.94.4  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3457:e0ff:fe61:78df/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:936 (936.0 B)  TX bytes:936 (936.0 B)
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C2:DB:44:D5:48:5D
          inet addr:169.254.0.4  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c0db:44ff:fed5:485d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3835 (3.7 KiB)  TX bytes:2392 (2.3 KiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

We get the following route table (again vnet specific on eth0)

```
default via 169.254.0.1 dev eth1
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.202.94.1 dev eth0
10.202.94.0/24 dev eth0  src 10.202.94.4
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  src 169.254.0.4
172.16.0.0/12 via 10.202.94.1 dev eth0
192.168.0.0/16 via 10.202.94.1 dev eth0
```

and the result of traceroute is as follows for google and one of our databases

```
/ # traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.193.78), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  169.254.0.1 (169.254.0.1)  0.007 ms  0.008 ms  0.005 ms
 2  *
```

```
# traceroute [ourdb].database.windows.net
traceroute to [ourdb].database.windows.net (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  169.254.0.1 (169.254.0.1)  0.008 ms  0.008 ms  0.005 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *
 4  *
```

An example of what I used to auto create a vnet with an instance on it.

```
az container create --resource-group rg-dev-aci --image alpine:latest --vnet vnet-dev-aci-east2  --subnet subnet-aci --subscription [my subscription id] --name test-alpine-networking-autovnet --command-line "tail -f /dev/null" --location "East US 2" --vnet-address-prefix 10.201.0.0/16 --subnet-address-prefix 10.201.94.0/24
```

It seems like something has changed with ACI (on VNET?) network configuration or something else with ACI. I know it is a preview feature of ACI, but I would not think that containers running in a VNET would be prevented from connecting to internet addresses.

Anyone have any ideas on what we could be doing wrong or what we could do to change things (like the default route's gateway). Is anyone else seeing the same issues?

Comment: Have you ever resolved this issue? We are running into the same actually..